# Export from Json to CSV without quotation marks?

Tags: javascript

I know CSV-files have quotation marks etc. but my export will be a certain import for a web-upload so I need to use CSV-files but without quotation marks

```
  downloadFile(data: any) {
    const replacer = (key, value) => value === null ? '' : value; // specify how you want to handle null values here
    const header = Object.keys(data[0]);
    let csv = data.map(row => header.map(fieldName => JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)).join(';'));
    csv.unshift(header.join(';'));
    let csvArray = csv.join('\r\n');

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff',csvArray], {type: 'text/csv'}),
    url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    a.href = url;
    a.download = "myFile.csv";
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    a.remove();
}
```

This is my code and everything works fine but I dont know where it puts those quotation marks in it.

Comment: *Don't build CSV files by hand.* Sooner or later you'll hit an edge case that breaks the whole thing. Install a CSV library where you can also specify if you want strings in the data to be enclosed in quotes or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in JSON are required to be delimited with quotes, so when you convert each header field **to JSON** they are added.

Don’t convert to JSON if you want plain strings!

---

You’ll almost certainly be better off using [a library](https://www.papaparse.com/) to generate your CSV instead of rolling your own though.